# I can't check radio button using jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have 2 radio buttons and I can't check them using jQuery ... 
What's wrong ?

HTML:

```
<table border="0">
<tr>
    <td style="width:85px;text-align:center;"><h4>Gender:</h4></td>
    <td style="width:85px;"><label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="maleradio" />Male</label></td>
    <td style="width:85px;"><label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" id="femaleradio"/>Female</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
 if (localStorage.getItem("gender") == "male") {
        console.log("Works fine");
        $("#maleradio").prop("checked", true);
    }
```

I get message "Works fine", but radio stay unchecked ...

Comment: did you get any error msg?

Comment: `jQuery("#maleradio").prop("checked", true);`

Comment: Check for duplicate `ids` (`maleradio`) on your page

Comment: Try with two equal sign, not three.

Comment: That doesn't matter because I get message "Works fine" which means statement is true :D @AltayMazlum

Comment: It should work... Are you sure you're not trolling us?

Comment: Why would I troll you ? It just doesent' work .. @AltayMazlum

Comment: No second id is "femaleradio" .. @RinoRaj

Comment: Can you add HTML with both inputs and full function... Or can you add a fiddle? which browser are you using? Version of jQuery ?

Comment: Browser is Chrome, I'm making apache cordova application and I'm working in Visual Studio.. jQuery version . 1.11.0 , jQuery mobile version - 1.4.3 , I will update my code @RinoRaj

Answer (score 3):

Use `.prop()` to set checked property:

```
jQuery("#maleradio").prop("checked", true);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m1yzpx9w/)**

**Update:** You need to make sure that dom element with id `maleradio` is loaded when above script is executed. You can ensure this by wrapping the script in document ready event.

Comment: @arma_best do you see errors in your error console?

Comment: I am working on apache cordova and I put this code inside "onDeviceReady" :D @MilindAnantwar

Comment: and how is the element loaded ??

Answer (score 0):

Give your Id value in `#Id` and execute the remaining statement.

```
$("#Id").prop("checked", true);
```

To get the value of the radio button

```
$("#Id").is(":checked");
```

If it is checked then it will return 'true' else 'false'

Comment: can you send your particular part

Comment: Yes that works in js fiddle but I nedd automatically on page load to check radio , that doesen't work for me ..